# How do I pass a person object into a related Post model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a basic beginner app to practice building in Rails.  I have scaffolded two models,a User, and a Post, a user has_many :posts and a post belongs_to a :user.

What I want is to make it so the show user page has a link to the new post so that the post is associated to the user and the submitted post has a little block showing the user who posted it.  I have the user_id field in the Post table.

the out-of-the-box functionality does not showthe associated user and I want it to.  How do I do this?

Comment: Do you mean "I want to show a link to the most recent post for a given user, if one exists?"

Comment: is this should be working after user signed in?

Answer (score 3):

You can do achieve this in multiple ways as per your need.

if you want to achieve if the user is already signed in you can do as follows:

in your PostController add this line to the create method

`@post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])`

this will automatically assign the user_id of the post for you.

add `<%= link_to "new_post", new_post_path %>` to the user show page.

other wise,

if the user not signed in

pass the user_id as a param in `new_post_path` link by adding

`<%= link_to "new_post", new_post_path(:user_id => user_id) %>` in the user show page

and in the new post page add the value to the `user_id` field as 
`<%= f.text_field :user_id, :value=>params[:user_id] $>` either you can make it as a hidden_field or text_field if you have to show the field